# Unable to resolve DNS over site-2-site VPN between Azure and on-prem

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, azure, virtual-network, windows-server-2019

I am running into some issues with setting up a test lab environment between on-prem and Azure. I have got as far as being able to get the site-2-site VPN up and connected and passing traffic (although not all).

I am not able to resolve DNS from Azure to on-prem. I have configured the Azure VM to use my on-prem DNS server via Azure (Not within the VM as reccomended) and confirmed this is set by running a ipconfig /all which shows 10.0.0.10.

I am able to RDP from on-prem to Azure and from Azure to on-prem so this proves that the site-2-site VPN is up and running.

I am able to browse the c$, again proving that the VPN is working.

I am however not able to resolve DNS queries against my on-prem DNS server and as a result I am not able to add the Azure VM to my on-prem AD.

I have added a custom suffix of lab.local within computer management

I have exhausted Microsoft KB's (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal)

I have even followed various how-to guides on how to set this up (mostly the same as the Microsoft KB's and again no luck.

Unfortunately I am now out of ideas and would appreciate some assistance.

Below is a basic run-down of my lab setup:

**On-Prem setup:**

Virtualised router = Pfsense (10.0.0.254)

Domain = lab.local

LAN subnet = 10.0.0.0/24

LAB-AC-DC01 = 10.0.0.10

LAB-AC-DC02 = 10.0.0.11

**Azure setup**

Site-2-Site VPN

VNet address space = 10.1.0.0/24

LAB-AZ-DC01 = 10.1.0.10

**Thank you in advance**

Comment: What does `nslookup` on the azure site say? Can it resolve your local DNS? If not there is just routing (think of BOTH ways) and your firewall (Dropping UDP maybe?).

Comment: nslookup comes back and reports a timeout

Local DNS (I presume you mean on-prem) works and I am able to domain join machines on-prem.

Comment: Then your DNS isn't able to resolve through it's counterpart. Check you routing. In many cases forget the back-route from the dns to the VPN gateway.